# Why $\operatorname{Aut}(A_5 )$ is isomorphic to $ S_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Why the automorphism group of $A_5$ is $S_5$?

I know that $A_5$ has $5$ Sylow-$2$ subgroups and there shall be a homomorphism from $\operatorname{Aut}(A_5)$ to $S_5$.

But how can I prove this homomorphism to be bijective?

Comment: Hint: each $2$-Sylow subgroup of $A_5$ is actually a $2$-Sylow subgroup of a copy of $A_4$ in $A_5$.

Comment: @Quang Hoang: I know the structure of those Sylow subgroups. I can actually write them down. But how can it help to solve my question? I don't understand that.

Comment: Each $2$-Sylow subgroup fixes one of the letters $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Let's call them $Syl_1,Syl_2,\dots, Syl_5$ correspondingly. It remains to show that a permutation of these groups defines a unique permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean in the question. What I can't go through is exactly how to prove such mapping is bijective.